# Django Channels + nuxt-socket-io not working

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nuxt.js, django-channels

I'm developing an app using Django as the backend framework and Vuex + Nuxt in the client-side. I tried to integrate websockets by using django-channels and nuxt-socket-io.
I cannot connect both libraries because django is exposing the websocket's urls with ws protocol (e.g. ws://localhost:8000/ws/roomName) and nuxt-socket-io library looks for the conection with http protocol. How can nuxt-socket-io library be configured to work with ws protocol or serve the django channels in the http protocol?

I leave here some of the main files that can be interesting to understand the configuration

## asgi.py

```
import logging

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import re_path

from apps.websockets.consumers import UserWebsocketConsumer

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
                re_path('ws/', UserWebsocketConsumer.as_asgi())
            ])
    ),
})
```

## nuxt.config

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '@nuxtjs/sentry' : ''
    '@nuxtjs/sentry',
    ['@nuxtjs/i18n',
      {
        strategy: 'no_prefix',
        locales: [
          { name: 'Español', code: 'es', iso: 'es-ES', file: 'es.js' },
          //{ name: 'English', code: 'en', iso: 'en-US', file: 'en.js' },
          { name: 'Català', code: 'ca', iso: 'ca-ES', file: 'ca.js' },
          //{ name: 'Code', code: 'code', iso: 'code', file: 'code.js' },
        ],
        //lazy: true,
        langDir: "i18n/",
        defaultLocale: process.env.DEFAULT_LANG || 'es',
        baseUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
        //detectBrowserLanguage: false,
        detectBrowserLanguage: {
          useCookie: true,
          cookieKey: 'django_language',
          redirectOn: 'root',  // recommended
        },
        vueI18n: {
          fallbackLocale: "es"
        }
      }
    ],
    'nuxt-socket-io'
  ],

  io: {
    sockets: [
        {
            name: 'django-backend',
            url: `ws://localhost:8000`,
            default: true
        }
    ],
```

If you need more details about some file or version of the libraries let me know